# Isabelle matrix arithmetic: det_linear_row_setsum in library with different notation

Tags: matrix, isabelle, theorem-proving

I recently started using the Isabelle theorem prover. As I want to prove another lemma, I would like to use a different notation than the one used in the lemma "det_linear_row_setsum", which can be found in the HOL library. More specifically, I would like to use the "χ i j notation" instead of "χ i". I have been trying to formulate an equivalent expression for some time, but couldn't figure it out yet.

```
(* ORIGINAL lemma from library *)
(* from HOL/Multivariate_Analysis/Determinants.thy *)
lemma det_linear_row_setsum:
  assumes fS: "finite S"
  shows "det ((χ i. if i = k then setsum (a i) S else c i)::'a::comm_ring_1^'n^'n) = setsum (λj. det ((χ i. if i = k then a  i j else c i)::'a^'n^'n)) S"
proof(induct rule: finite_induct[OF fS])
  case 1 thus ?case apply simp  unfolding setsum_empty det_row_0[of k] ..
next
  case (2 x F)
  then  show ?case by (simp add: det_row_add cong del: if_weak_cong)
qed
```

..

```
(* My approach to rewrite the above lemma in χ i j matrix notation *)
lemma mydet_linear_row_setsum:
  assumes fS: "finite S"
  fixes A :: "'a::comm_ring_1^'n^'n" and k :: "'n"  and vec1 :: "'vec1 ⇒ ('a, 'n) vec"
  shows "det ( χ r c . if r = k then (setsum (λj .vec1 j $ c) S) else A $ r $ c ) =
    (setsum (λj . (det( χ r c . if r = k then vec1 j $ c else A $ r $ c ))) S)" 
proof-
  show ?thesis sorry
qed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make yourself clear what the original lemma says: `a` is a family of vectors indexed by `i` and `j`, `c` is a family of vectors indexed by `i`. The `k`-th row of the matrix on the left is the sum of the vectors `a k j` ranged over all `j` from the set `S`.
The other rows are taken from `c`. On the right, the matrices are the same except that row `k` is now `a k j` and the `j` is bound in the outer sum.

As you have realised, the family of vectors `a` is only used for the index `i = k`, so you can replace `a` by `%_ j. vec1 $ j`. Your matrix `A` yields the family of rows, i.e., `c` becomes `%r. A $ r`. Then, you merely have to exploit that `(χ n. x $ n) = x` (theorem `vec_nth_inverse`) and push the `$` through the `if` and `setsum`. The result looks as follows:

```
lemma mydet_linear_row_setsum:
  assumes fS: "finite S"
  fixes A :: "'a::comm_ring_1^'n^'n" and k :: "'n" and vec1 :: "'vec1 => 'a^'n"
  shows "det (χ r c . if r = k then setsum (%j. vec1 j $ c) S else A $ r $ c) =
    (setsum (%j. (det(χ r c . if r = k then vec1 j $ c else A $ r $ c))) S)"
```

To prove this, you just have to undo the expansion and the pushing through, the lemmas `if_distrib`, `cond_application_beta`, and `setsum_component` might help you in doing so.